# Recursively find files ending with specified pattern

Tags: linux, find, regular-expression, filenames

I have a lot of folders with files ending with "-105x135.jpg", "-410x410.jpg" etc., "780-105x135.jpg" and "candyswing-2-klein-ohrringe-schale-038-135x160.jpg" for example which i need to find and delete, using online regex I've created this pattern: `[0-9]x..[0-9].jpg`, but `find . -regex '[0-9]x..[0-9].jpg'`
didn`t show any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `man` page, the `-regex` option is a match on the *entire path*, ie. the *entire* file name **and** also the entire directory-path portion, so you would need to precede your regex with `.*`. There are several explicit examples in the `man` page.

Also, keep in mind the option `-regextype`. The default (per the `man` page) is `emacs`, but other options are `posix-awk`, `posix-basic`, `posix-egrep` and `posix-extended`. Knock yourself out.

Comment: Thanks! It did work, but besides adding `.*` I needed to replace periods with `[0-9]`, for some reason periods didn't work. I ended up with `find -regex ".*[09]x[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg"`

Comment: Great to hear. If you're game to continue experimenting, try `".*[09]x[0-9]+.jpg"` and `".*[09]x[0-9]{3}.jpg"`

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use bash's globstar option:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

to list:

```
ls **/*[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg
```

or remove:

```
rm **/*[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg
```

the files.

The glob pattern above is slightly different that the regex you provided; the regex would allow *any* two characters after the `x`, not strictly numbers. In other words, a file named: `somefile-135xyz9.jpg` would match the regex, but not the above glob.

The glob recursively (`**`) matches files that:

- start with anything (`*`)
- have three numbers (three `[0-9]`)
- followed by an `x`
- followed by three numbers
- followed by `.jpg`

One risk to this approach is if/when the number of matching files exceeds the command-line argument space. In that case, you could save the filenames in an array, then loop through the array individually.

To investigate:

```
files=(**/*[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do echo Would: rm -- "$file"; done
```

To remove:

```
files=(**/*[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do rm -- "$file"; done
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it gave me `bash: /usr/bin/ls: Argument list too long` error.

Comment: @Mike, I've added a workaround to the end of my post, in case it's useful for you.